# Paysafe how to rebill with C# SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, paysafe

I'd like to know how we can use if it even still exists, the "rebill" API with the C# SDK.

We are migrating from the "Hosted Payments API" to a combination of Paysafe.js for the frontend and C# SDK for the backend. We now want to use the Single-Use Token.

My scenario is the following.

- I created an invoice
- Add two items to it.
- I pay the invoice entirely.
- I want to issue a refund for only of the item.

From my understanding, every 24 hours, every payment are processed and marked as "COMPLETED". Once a payment is marked as "COMPLETED" it can be refunded using the "Refund" API. If a payment isn't "COMPLETED" I have to use the "CancelSettlement" API.

"CancelSettlement" cancels the whole payment. Now my problem is that, with Single-Use Token, how do I "Rebill" my client for the item that wasn't cancelled?

With the "Hosted Payments API" we would use the "Rebill" Api but now?